# Is it okay to have a DynamoDB table with a SHA256 Key?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, sha256

I'm creating a User Table on DynamoDB, and I wanted to set the primary key as a sha256 hash string of the user's email address.

Is it a good idea to keep a SHA256 value as a primary key in a DynamoDB table? Would this be better for lookups or worse?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that the primary key uniquely identifies each item in a DynamoDB table,
 
Which can be simple (a partition key only) or composite (a partition key combined with a sort key).

SHA-256 generates an **almost-unique** 256-bit (32-byte) signature for a text.
An alternative is using UUID V1 for being used as Primary keys,

**Here's an interesting content on the use of UUID -**
https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/10/05/uuid1-vs-uuid4/

**Best Practices for Designing and Using Partition Keys Effectively -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html